# What's the proper way to modify an existing FMX control?

Tags: user-controls, customization, firemonkey, tmemo

I need to modify the behavior of the built-in FMX TMemo control. I never done this before and want to know what's the proper way to do it. Under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\fmx` I found there are several related files:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\fmx\FMX.Memo.iOS.pas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\fmx\FMX.Memo.Android.pas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\fmx\FMX.Memo.Win.pas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\fmx\FMX.Memo.Types.pas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\fmx\FMX.Memo.Style.pas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\fmx\FMX.Memo.Style.New.pas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\fmx\FMX.Memo.pas

Should I copy them to the root of my current project folder and start editing them? Should I rename `TMemo` in these files to some other name, or can I just use `TMemo`? What else should I do to let my application code recognize them instead of the built-in `TMemo`?

Btw, I'm using Delphi 10.4.2 on Windows.

Comment: You are supposed to copy them to your project folder and edit them.

Comment: If you can simply inherit from the TMemo component, it is a lot easier to manage.